# Что делать, если "div" мешает работе "p"?

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно выровнять текст по центу, но "div" мешает "p" и в css text-align не работает. Что можно с этим сделать?

```js
(function() {
  var preload = document.getElementById("preloader");
  var loading = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 64);

  function frame() {
    if (loading == 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      loading = loading + 1;
      if (loading == 90) {
        preload.style.opacity = "0";
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.panel {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: 2s;
}

.panel a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
  color: black;
  transition: 2s;
}

.panel a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

#onthepanel1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Proba</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body bgcolor="purple" margin="0" padding="0">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel">
      <p id="onthepanel1">
        <a href="#Global">Global</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Все работает. Элемент `<a>` не выравнивается по центру только из-за наличия float: left в стиле для `.panel a`. Если поместить в `<p>` любой другой элемент, он выравнивается по центру.

Answer (score 1):

Ты хочешь чтоб элементы в теге `<p>` были посередине?
Убери у тега `<а>` свойство `float: left` и все будет работать.

Comment: Дополните свой ответ – например, рабочим кодом или ссылками на документацию.

Answer (score 0):

используй `<span>` вместо `<div>`. `<div>` - блочный, а `<span>` - строчный элементы. Поэтому `<div>` формирует блок из того, что в нем располагается с новой строки, а `<span>` не переносит элементы, размещая их в строку. Так же стоит отметь, что согласно рекомендациям w3c линейный тег не может включать в себя блочные теги, поэтому `<div>` обычно используется для разметки блоков, а `<span>` - отрывков текста.

Comment: Дополните свой ответ – например, рабочим кодом или ссылками на документацию.

Comment: Я поменял <div> на <span> и у меня пропала панель, а <p> не заработал))